# What is the best practice for auto switching from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: php, http, ssl, https

I'm curious. What is the best practice to auto switch the user from http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com

i.e. from *http* to *https*? Ideally I would like to make it so that no matter what the url (and any possible get data)

There are a couple things people chat about like checking `$_SERVER ["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]` or `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']` or `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` but I would like to know what the best practice is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force SSL/https using .htaccess and mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398951/force-ssl-https-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force SSL HTTPS With Zend Framework and mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329647/force-ssl-https-with-zend-framework-and-mod-rewrite)

Comment: @Gordon you are duplicate finding king!

Comment: @alex http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/11?m=453322#453322 ;)

Comment: yea I was looking for a way to do it with PHP not .htaccess file though it seems the best way to do it IS by .htaccess

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### PHP

If you want to force `http` to `https`, do this...

```
if ( ! isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
   header('Location: https://' . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

However, if your site has a custom port, you'll also need to add `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']`. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` also isn't set on IIS, in case you are using it.

#### Apache .htaccess / httpd.conf

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

redirect it before the request reach the real app server, i.e. redirect it on reverse proxy like nginx/apache.

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines in your .htaccess file in the root directory of your site

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yousite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

also if you have just some directory that you want to secure (e.g. the directory where the login script is found), then put an .htaccess file into that directory containing these lines

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /path/to/directory
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yousite.com/path/to/directory/$1 [R,L]
```