# How do I set it up so people come to my https website, not the http version?

Tags: http, https

I set up my website as http, but have improved the security to https - problem is, the search engines still link to the http version.

How do i get it so that if someone were to go to my http website, they would get moved to the https version?

the website is www.easy-bingo.co.uk if anyone has any other tips they would want to throw my way!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you are running apache, you can use the answer given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess

Comment: What's the web server you're using? You should be able to forward the http requests to https there.

Comment: i'm not running apache, and I'm using godaddy webhosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with the .htaccess file by adding some rewrite rules, see post: [htaccess redirect to https://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977851/htaccess-redirect-to-https-www)

I am not sure how this will affect search engines though.

Comment: thanks guys, i think my basic mistake was setting up as a windows server as opposed to linux - i switched it and the software is now part of the tools that do it automatically anyway... no idea why i went with windows in the first place - call it ignorance. Thanks Again