# How work with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

need do auto redirect to `https://www....` with SEO, i have that code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA] // that for SEO variable
```

How i can do, if customer use `http://` auto redirect to `https://www.*` AND if use `https://name.com` (without `www.`) auto redirect to `https://www.*` ? and too with variable $1 for SEO :) need to supplement the existing rule, sorry for my English)

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this under `Rewritebase /`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: don't work, if i remove `https://` (manually) he redirect to `https://www.www......` if i remove `wwww.` then all is well (adds it back), and SEO don't work, SEO work if that code `RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @Dimitrylmz I have no clue what you're saying