# Https Redirection Issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, https

I'm using Cloudflare's SSL on Flexible (Free) and it works perfectly fine.
I have setup all files and links from `https://` to `//` to make them work over https.

I have also set the following in my `.htaccess` file to make any client go from http to https automatically:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^(443(s)|[0-9]+s)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=askapache:%2]
```

The issue with the `.htaccess` code is that it only changes http to https on the root index file of my site for example, `http://example.com/index.php` will redirect to `https` but `http://example.com/folder/index.php` wont.

My second issue is even if I do a simple `href="https://example.com/folder/index.php"` or `href="//example.com/folder/index.php"` it will just bring me to the basic http url.

Comment: Why do you not use [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess) ?

Comment: All the answers do work and rediretc from http to https but I get a redirect loop disallowing the page to load.

Comment: Check if apache ssl conf is correctly setup ;)

Comment: Ill go onto live chat with my hosting provider see if they cna help.

Comment: They couldnt help :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CloudFlare, you can define to always use SSL in the page rules.

---

For .htaccess (recursive):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: How can I define to always use SSL via page rules?

Comment: @YuukiAsuna: See the help of [CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-). For the loop: very crazy. What does the server logs say?