# How to redirect to https with .htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, https, web

I want to redirect everyone that enters my website into https://www.yogozy.com/
Now whenever I type yogozy.com on the search bar it takes me automatically to yogozy.com but since I have my SSL activated I want everyone that enters my 
website to be redirected to https://www.yogozy.com

Is that possible to do using .htaccess?

If yes can you please guide me through the process?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess/10489949), you can try the following:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```