# How to force Laravel to generate https link?

Tags: php, ssl, https, laravel-5, cloudflare

I am using cloudflare CDN to "supercharged" my site and I am using it's full SSL for better security for my site. However, I am frequently experiencing `error 523` on my site. I have consult help for both cloudflare and hosting company, but both were saying no problem with their side. So, I have to do my own experiment try to fix the problem.

Now, I try to make the full SSL to flexi SSL. Because the connection between server and Cloudflare were done with insecure connection (`http`), therefore the generated link by laravel all are in `http` format. This brings problem that all my CSS & JS doesn't load on Firefox and return with the error saying `Blocked loading mixed active content`.

So, how can I force Laravel to generate URL with the `https` connection?

Comment: i don't know `laravel`.  but i think you can do it through `htaccess`.  see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess)

Comment: how does your current code look?

Comment: @patricus My code looks something like this `asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')` and `url($language.'/index')`

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce `https` in a route, such as:

```
Route::get('order/details/{id}', ['uses' => 'OrderController@details', 'as' => 'order.details', 'https']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the `asset()` and the `url()` helper methods take a `$secure` boolean as their last parameter. If you pass this in as `true`, the methods will generate secure urls:

```
// pass true as second parameter to asset
asset('css/bootstrap.min.css', true)

// pass true as third parameter to url
url($language.'/index', [], true)
```