# redirect the URL https://www.domain.com into https://www.domain.com/

Tags: .htaccess

I want to add the trailing slashes at the end of the domain name.

For example, redirect from https://www.eatonline.dk to https://www.eatonline.dk/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http to https through .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess)

Comment: share your htaccess

Answer (score 1):

You can keep you dynamically changing URL in an variable and can add the slash at the end

For example : 
   var URL = "www.eatonline.dk" (You can assign the value as dynamically here ).
   url = url + "/";
Now the URL variable will have the value as "www.eatonline.dk/" which is still an link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to add trailing slash to all urls

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

it will redirect:

> https:// www.eatonline.dk   >     https:// www.eatonline.dk/

**and also**

> https:// www.eatonline.dk/test   >    https:// www.eatonline.dk/test/