# Redirect from wordpress htaccess to http to https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, ssl, https

This is my wordpress htaccess file code.After active ssl certificate now i want to redirect http to https.But it's not working.What is .well-known/acheme-challenge?This folder exist on my root folder.Can anyone help me

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !
^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]  {32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !
^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]  {32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`enter code here`
```

# END WordPress

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http to https through .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess)

Comment: Hi @Biscuit.Its not working,what is .well-known/achme-challenge

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Please refer to https://serverguy.com/servers/redirect-http-to-https/

Comment: How about using `header()` redirection? Like `($_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] != 'https') ? header('location:https://www.example.com') : null;`

Comment: Thanks.I changed on htaccess file.But also will try your solution