# .htaccess keeps replacing URI with index.php

Tags: .htaccess, magento-1.8

We have made a flyer were a URL is printed at which looks like this:

```
mycompany.de/special
```

But if a user actually enters this URL, then he is getting redirected to the startpage *https://www.mycompany.de/index.php* instead of getting redirected to *https://www.mycompany.de/special*

This is my .htaccess so far, it forces https and www:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

That works almost as expected, the only problem is that `/special` is getting removed and replaced by `/index.php`. The question is, why is `special` getting replaced?

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain)

Comment: @starkeen, how is this related to my question?

Comment: @PedroRodrigues, this is not related to my question at all, how is this a duplicate?

Comment: What exactly is not working for you?

Comment: Im not sure what informations are missing, I added all necessary infos to my question @starkeen.

Comment: Sorry but the rule you posted looks ok and it works for me.

Comment: Is `/special` a real directory?

Comment: You're joking right? Not related to your question, how can you argument that may I ask. It is related to your question, and you should not expect any further comments from me on this, unless you state what is that your not being able to achieve. Don't expect someone to do your work, there's plenty of gentleman waiting to help you; help them doing it. I'm out.

Comment: @pedroRodrigues by the way , "Redirecting to new site" was not the question :)

Comment: @starkeen, No /special is just a route. I am working with Magento and created the site as a CMS page. The actual content is stored in the database.

Comment: I think it's Magento the problem : .htaccess should work. There is something else that redirect the page after it. Or provide full .htaccess if there is other conditions.

Comment: @Shim-Sao, my condition is at the bottom of the .htaccess file, so It can't get overwritten. I will check if magento is the cause by commenting out code at the index.php

Comment: I don't understand why it can't get overwritten ?

Comment: @Shim-Sao, you are right, that was a dumb comment. It CAN be overwritten, and it was overwritten :/ I found the solution and will post it

Comment: Rule that you've shown must be placed before all other rules and then clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/special
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```