# How to change shared blogs on LinkedIn and Facebook from http to https?

Tags: .htaccess, http, ssl, https

Just updated my website with SSL, but there are already some shared blogs on LinkedIn and on Facebook.

If I open the blogs from Facebook or LinkedIn, it's only http, because when they were shared, the site was not secure yet.

Currently the site have SSL and when I open the blogs from there, everything is fine.

The site uses wordpress, but with a custom theme created by me.

Is there a way to force them to use https? Can I modify htaccess.php somehow to force the shared links to use https instead of http?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but you can redirect a http request to a https request: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10489949/9710338