# www.example.co.uk is not redirecting to https://www.example.co.uk

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have created `.htaccess` file rules. when i used without `example.co.uk` site get redirect to `https://www.example.co.uk` but when i tried `www.example.co.uk` then its not redirecting to `https://www.example.co.uk`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co.uk$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

is anyone has any suggestion what went wrong? with this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [http to https through .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess)

Comment: "when i used without `example.co.uk`" - don't you mean "with"?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your first condition *explicitly* makes sure that the redirection only will get applied when the requested host name is exactly "example.co.uk". So *not* "www.example.co.uk". You can change that condition to accept *both* variants:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co\.uk$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END]
```