# Force SSL Connection During / After User Login

Tags: php, ssl, https

I have a php application in place. I'm working on installing an SSL certificate on my web host and forcing all connections during login and after login to use the certificate. How would I go about this? Do I just have a simple force SSL on the login page, and then everything after will remain on the SSL port?

```
if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on")
{
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    exit();
}
```

Will something like that on my login page force the SSL connection for the user even after login? The reason I need SSL after login is that the php application requires and handles a lot of company financial data.

If I needed the code on each page, this would screw up sending post data as the header redirect would not carry the post data a long with it.

Comment: you can do this in .htacess

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force SSL/HTTPS with Zend Framework and mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329647/force-ssl-https-with-zend-framework-and-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to not have all connections secured.

in your .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: But remember, when you have an ssl connection, the browser will not cache your website data. Hence your site will be slow. So understand ssl well and implement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that one variable is kinda confusing. It's [only present if you're using SSL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"])) // SSL
```

As mentioned by other answers, this really is best left to the web server configuration. All of them have ways of forcing SSL