# Redirecting in website using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web, redirect

Can any one please help me how redirect all `http://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com`. I have recently purchased an ssl for my site and hence needed it to be redirected. Redirecting using .htaccess will be more useful for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are several answers linked under `Related` on RHS. Did you try any of them?

Comment: Like @anubhava said, there are a lot of answers on the site for this questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force SSL/HTTPS with Zend Framework and mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329647/force-ssl-https-with-zend-framework-and-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions out there. Here is a link to the apache wiki which deals with this issue directly.

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```