# Issue with Laravel 5.2 and His non-persistent App SetLocale over http://

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-5, setlocale

Can anyone point me in the right direction when trying to troubleshoot this web app ([Dorothea Special School](http://www.dorotheaschool.co.za)) I created a few years back using this link [Laravel 5 And His F*cking non-persistent App SetLocale](http://www.dorotheaschool.co.za)

If I can recall it was working perfectly when I 1st published the web app, but for a while now it doesn't seem to be working correctly...  I think I did check the log file on the server and a couple more things to no avail.  Do you think I need to run a composer cmd on the server?

Comment: Things to try: `App::setLocale('nl_NL');` and on server level `apt-get install locales-all`

Comment: Hi Thomas Moors thanks I just noticed now that if I use https://... instead of http://... it seems to be working 100%, so would your comment above still apply?

Comment: No I think not, this probably has to do with your session cookie only be set trough https. In config/session.php you have an option called `secure` (line 164 on my installation) which you might want to set to false.

Comment: https://imgur.com/ukJGT8G

Comment: @Thomas Moors great thanks, but if I set it to false will it work correctly for http://... and https://... or only http://... then?  If it's only going to work for http://... then it's kind of a catch 22.  Wouldn't it be better / easier to rather redirect all http://... to https://... then?
What are your thoughts?

Comment: yes https only would be best

Comment: Thanks very much for all the help :-).
You must add all your comments as an answer when you have time then I can mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options: only allow https through redirecting http or disabling secure for cookies in your config.