# Laravel redirect to HTTPS even if i'm already under HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel, https, middleware

I have a middleware to rediret to HTTPS like so:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class HttpsProtocolMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->secure() && app()->environment('production')) {
            dd("need to redirect");
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

However it is not working since if go to `https://project.domain.com` i get a `too many redirection` from the browser (and now with the `dd` I see the dumo even if i go to my website through HTTPS)

EDIT:
I've already tested adding

```
Request::setTrustedProxies([$request->getClientIp()],Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL);
```

as first line, and in `TrustProxies`

```
protected $proxies = '*';
```

but without success

Comment: Something else is probably redirecting (apache/nginx) to http (and the $request->secure() returns false)...check the actual requests/redirects being made in chrome dev tools (network tab)

Comment: @RokSprogar which header show I check?

Comment: @RokSprogar if you want... `https://gestionale-marco.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: What's your environment?

Comment: @James I've deployed the project on Heroku

Comment: To be more specific, what is the `APP_ENV` in your `.env` file?

Comment: @James `production` otherwise it won't redirect never

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329647/force-ssl-https-with-mod-rewrite/34065445#34065445

Comment: @RokSprogar i can't use that method, I would have no control over te enviroment that I'm working on

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to why you are experiencing what you are. But you could remove that middleware

and add

```
if(app()->environment('production')) {
   \Url::forceSchema('https') 
}
```

To your `AppServiceProvider.php`

Will do the same thing

Comment: this would generate the `route(...)` and `url(...)` with HTTP, but wont' redirect the user if he is on a HTTP page

Comment: Then just add that to top of routes file instead of appServiceProvider